# Check if SWF has focus

Tags: javascript, actionscript

How can I check if a SWF element on a page has focus?

In IE,  `onkeydown` events are not detected in JavaScript if a SWF has focus but Firefox always detects `onkeydown`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Detect it with Javascript? Javascript has `onFocus` and `onBlur` events,

```
var hasFocus=false;

DomElem.addEventListener('focus', function(e){
    hasFocus=true;
},false);

DomElem.addEventListener('blur', function(e){
    hasFocus=false;
},false);
```

I'm not sure about how to do it in AS...

Answer (score 1):

I think there is an [Event.ACTIVATE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#ACTIVATE) triggered when flash gets the focus.
you can also listen to a MOUSE_OUT on the stage to check when flash loses the focus.